# 404 error on a file/directory that exists?

Tags: htaccess, apache2, 404

We are using the vBulletin system.

I have set it up so that it redirects 404 errors to a PHP page, so it follows the theme of the forum.

However, if I go to a directory that exists (the `admin` directory to be precise), I get the 404 error.

The folder in question is `.htaccess` password protected, as well as leech protected. And this is happening to all `.htaccess` protected directories.

My `.htaccess` code is below:

```
RewriteEngine on

# 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?do=404
ErrorDocument 403 /errors.php?do=403
ErrorDocument 500 /errors.php?do=500

# If you are having problems or are using VirtualDocumentRoot, uncomment this line and set it to your vBulletin directory.
# RewriteBase /forum/

# If you are having problems with the rewrite from content/ to content.php, uncomment this line to turn MultiViews off.
# Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Forum
RewriteRule ^threads/.* showthread.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/.* forumdisplay.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^members/.* member.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/.* blog.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^entries/.* entry.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# MVC
RewriteRule ^(?:(.*?)(?:/|$))(.*|$)$ $1.php?r=$2 [QSA]

# Check MVC result
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: There appears to be a workaround for Wordpress at the following URL, your issue sounds similar: http://systembash.com/content/password-protected-folder-gives-404-not-found-in-wordpress-installation-sub-folder/